# I don't like the "new desktop" provided by 11.10. How do I get the old one back?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I'm not sure what this new desktop is called. But things I dislike:

1. When I hover my mouse on the top of the screen, a menu shows. In the past, the menu is always there.
2. The new panel on the left. I dislike such style...
3. Where's the bar at the bottom? The one that shows the windows currently opened, etc.

I did some google work and found [this](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/09/11/install-the-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-11-10/). But the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` only gives the error: `E: Package 'gnome-panel' has no installation candidate`.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to add the 'old' desktop, but you do have quite a few options.

1. Install Xubuntu or Lubuntu to get that old desktop feel again. Not exactly the same       but darn close.
2. Install LXDE, or XFCE, which will allow you to select those DE's at login to have that old style desktop.
3. Install a distro that still uses Gnome 2.x  << Not many left that do.
4. Look in to cinnamon, which is a gnome shell that is being written by the LinuxMint team. It is supposed to have that same old style feel with some new and enhanced tweaks.

Good luck and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, dtigue. But, if I just install an old version of Ubuntu, will upgrading the system inside the old one bring the new desktop as well?

Comment: You can simply do (1) `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` (2) log out, (3) select Xubuntu session from the gear on the login screen, (4) tweak your desktop to resemble the "old" (gnome2). Edit: A warning: installing xubuntu-desktop will add an ugly (at least to me) loading screen when your computer is booting up.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-panel` was a part of Gnome 2, and since Ubuntu no packs Gnome 3 it's no longer available. Have a look at [cinnamon](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/cinnamon-12-released-with-desktop.html) which is a fork of gnome-shell with a more classic look and feel and see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

you may wish to try `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` as i believe it is asking you to use its fallback mode labelled gnome classic

although if you're going for the classic feel i recommend cinnamon linked above in another answer although this has issues unless you are using the open source ATI driver

Answer (score 0):

You may use cinnamon or:

Install Gnome 3: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

And then use it as Gnome Classic.
It's the most "close" you can get.